How can I implement a background call-like feature with the device’s default ringtone?
In my React Native Expo project, I want to implement a background call-like feature. We are developing a taxi booking application, and I need to show an incoming trip notification, similar to a call, even when the app is in the background or closed. The notification should trigger the device's ringtone as well
I tried using expo-notifications, expo-task-manager, and expo-background-fetch, but the background tasks are not working properly. While expo-notifications is functioning, I’m not sure how to access the device’s ringtone.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
